# How to set one column automatically to 0, on entering value to the other (like Debit & Credit) in php?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a form, including debit and credit columns. But I don't know how to set one column to be zero, on entering value to the other. (Like, if the value is entered to the debit column, credit must be zero, without accepting any values, and vice versa). I tried something, which is not working.
My code is....

````
                var dId=$(this).data('id');
                var at=dId.replace('debit','');
                    //var at=dId.charAt(5);
                    var cr=$("#credit"+at).text();
                    var acc=$("#dr"+at).val();
                    if(acc==""){
                      $("#dr"+at).focus();
                      toastr.info("Select an account first","info");
                      $("#dr"+at).focus();
                      //setTimeout(function() { $("#dr"+at).focus() }, 3000);
                    }else{
                     if(cr==""){
                       //$(this).text(0);
                       $("#debit"+at).attr('contenteditable',true);
                      calc_total();
                      }
                      else if(cr==0){
                       $("#debit"+at).attr('contenteditable',true);
                      calc_total();
                      }
                      else{ 
                        $(this).text(0);
                       $(this).attr('contenteditable',false);
                      calc_total();
                      }
                    }
             })    
             $("body").on('click', '.credit', function(e) {
                var dId=$(this).data('id');
                var at=dId.replace('credit','');
                //var at=dId.charAt(6);
                var dr=$("#debit"+at).text();
                var acc=$("#dr"+at).val();
                if(acc==""){
                  $("#dr"+at).focus();
                  toastr.info("Select an account first","info");
                  $("#dr"+at).focus();
                  $("#acctCol").focus();
                  //setTimeout(function() { $("#dr"+at).focus() }, 3000);
                }else{
                 if(dr==""){
                  // $(this).text(0);
                   $("#credit"+at).attr('contenteditable',true);
                  calc_total1(); 
                  }
                  else if(dr==0){
                   $("#credit"+at).attr('contenteditable',true);
                  calc_total1(); 
                  }
                  else{ 
                    $(this).text(0);
                   $(this).attr('contenteditable',false);
                  calc_total1(); 
                 }
                } 
             })     ```
````

Comment: Can you edit with you php code.

Answer (score -1):

no need to change in php code.just set default value 0 in your field like in your table click on structure then in action click on change then set default value 0 [image]

Comment: I want the form in the front end, not in the database. By the way, thanks for responding...